# Pass variable to extended PHP class

Tags: php, oop

I've been using OOP in PHP for a while now, but for some reason am having a total brain meltdown and can't work out what's going wrong here!

I have a much more complex class, but wrote a simpler one to test it, and even this isn't working...

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class test
{
    public $testvar;

    function __construct()
    {
       $this->testvar = 1;
    }
}

class test2 extends test
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->testvar;
    }
}

$test = new test;
$test2 = new test2;
```

All I'm trying to do is pass a variable from the parent class to the child class! I swear in the past I've just used **$this->varName** to get **$varName** in the extension??

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to call the constructor of the parent class from the constructor of the child class.

Which means, in your case, that your `test2` class will then become :

```
class test2 extends test
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $this->testvar;
    }
}
```

For more informations, you can take a look at the page [Constructors and Destructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of the manual, which states, about your question :

> Note:  **Parent constructors are not
>   called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor**. In order to run
>   a parent constructor, a call to
>   `parent::__construct()` within the
>   child constructor is required.

You can use `$this->varName` : this is not a problem ; consider this code :

```
class test {
    public $testvar = 2;
    function __construct() {
       $this->testvar = 1;
    }
}
class test2 extends test {
    function __construct() {
        var_dump($this->testvar);
    }
}
$test2 = new test2;
```

The output is :

```
int 2
```

Which is the "default" value of `$testvar`.

This means the problem is not that you cannot access that property : the problem, here, is only that the constructor of the parent class has not been called.

Answer (score 2):

Your `test2` class should call

```
parent::__construct()
```

in its constructor.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could add this as the accepted answer as well!